# Pandas dataframe custom formatting string to time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
          DEP_TIME
0         1851
1         1146
2         2016
3         1350
4          916
          ...
607341     554
607342     633
607343     657
607344     705
607345     628
```

I need to get every value in this column `DEP_TIME` to have the format `hh:mm`.
All cells are of type `string` and can remain that type.

Some cells are only missing the colon (rows 0 to 3), others are also missing the leading 0 (rows 4+).
Some cells are empty and should ideally have string value of 0.

I need to do it in an efficient way since I have a few million records. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['DEP_TIME'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['DEP_TIME'], format='%H%M', errors='coerce')
                   .dt.strftime('%H:%M')
                   .fillna('00:00'))

print (df)
       DEP_TIME
0         18:51
1         11:46
2         20:16
3         13:50
4         09:16
607341    05:54
607342    06:33
607343    06:57
607344    07:05
607345    06:28
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

d = [['1851'],
['1146'],
['2016'],
 ['916'],
      ['814'],
     [''],
[np.nan]]

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['DEP_TIME'])

df['DEP_TIME'] = df['DEP_TIME'].fillna('0')
df['DEP_TIME'] = df['DEP_TIME'].apply(lambda y: '0' if y=='' else re.sub(r'(\d{1,2})(\d{2})$', lambda x: x[1].zfill(2)+':'+x[2], y))

df
```

```
    DEP_TIME
0   18:51
1   11:46
2   20:16
3   09:16
4   08:14
5   0
```